# Create a conditional TTL in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

There is a particular task I want to accomplish, but I am not finding any particular way to do that.
Let's say I have an app that is used to send mails. I keep a record of these emails in a collection in mongo. And using this app I can send mail right now or can schedule emails for future.
The structure of documents in collection is like :

```
{
'_id' : 123456789,
'to_email' : 'xyz@gmail.com'
'from_email' : 'abc@gmail.com'
'subject': 'some subject'
'type' : '<1 if normal and 2 if scheduled>',
'createdDate' '<date when mail was sent or the request was created>',
'scheduledDate' : '<time for which mail is scheduled>'
.. and many more key-value pairs
}
```

The `scheduledDate` field can be zero or any date, depending on if it's scheduled or not.
I don't want to keep data which is older than 2 days, so I created a TTL index on 'createdDate', for 2 days.
But I also don't want to delete rows or requests which are scheduled for the future.
I was looking for some kind of conditional TTL, but couldn't find any such solution.

Is there anything available like conditional TTL or any other way to do it in MongoDB.

I want to create a TTL which work like :

```
if(requestType!=2 and createdDate < -2days)
delete row;
```

or is there a way where I can make changes to certain documents using any language so that they don't get expired.

EDIT: I solved this, by using the same values for `scheduledDate` and `createdDate` in case of scheduled emails.

Comment: please share the schema type for scheduledDate. I tried to create type: Date, and default: new Date(). So if entry is zero then it will be deleted under 5 minutes and if entry have date then it won't be delete. But after inserting i check that instead of 0 time format save with ISO (00:00:00-000z) like this. I want to initial store 0 (number format) and then when condition arise it will save current ISO date timestamp. So that after specific minute only 0 oen will remove

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As of MongoDB 3.2, it is also possible to add a partial TTL index using a specified filter expression. In case if you need to remove only normal not scheduled emails, you could use the following:

```
db.email.createIndex( {createdDate: 1}, {
    expireAfterSeconds: 172800, // 2 days
    partialFilterExpression: {
        scheduledDate: 0
    }
});
```

Note that `partialFilterExpression` has restrictions on possible filter conditions: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/

Answer (score 14):

I would just add another field. It's not that much data:

```
{
'_id' : 123456789,
'createdDate' '<date when mail was sent or the request was created>',
'scheduledDate' : '<time for which mail is scheduled>'
'expires': '<Date or NULL>'
}
```

Add a TTL index of 0 seconds to the expires field. Don't add a TTL to the other dates.

The following examples are in Mongoose (an ORM for Node) but the ideas should carry over to whatever framework you're using:

## A default value

You could add a default value to the expires field with the value of 'created date + 2 days'.

```
{
  type: Date,
  default: function() { 
    return new Date(Date.now() + 1000*60*60*24*2);
  }
}
```

## A different expire date for your scheduled tasks

Just set the date explicitly:

```
myNewDocument.expires = new Date( scheduled + ... );
```

Or change the function that sets the default value:

```
function() {
    if(this.get("type") === 2) {
      return scheduled_date_plus_2_days;
    } else {
      return created_date_plus_2_days;
    }
}
```

## No expiry at all

Set the field to NULL:

```
myNewDocument.expires = null;
```

---

This way, you have the ability to choose a different expiry for normal emails, important emails, scheduled ones, etc. If you're on time, you can even set the `expires` field to NULL to cancel the automatic deletion.
The only caveat is that if you change the scheduled time, you'll need to update the expires field.

Comment: So you would add the index needed to expire it like this [(Docs)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time)? `db.emails.createIndex( { "expires": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )`

Comment: That looks correct to me: In your case, the document will be deleted when the current date is the value of the `expires` field (give or take a minute).

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a TTL index on `scheduledDate`, if the value is zero it will not be deleted. According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/), if the indexed field in a document is not a date or an array that holds a date value(s), the document will not expire.

Using Mongo 3.2 I have verified this is indeed the case using this test collection:

```
db.data.drop()
db.data.save({scheduledDate: 0})
db.data.save({scheduledDate: new Date()})
db.data.save({scheduledDate: new Date()})
db.data.createIndex( { "scheduledDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds:1} )
```

When using this collection all `new Date()` entries get removed , whereas the first record with the zero value remains

Comment: but if there is another TTL index set for 'createdDate', then also it wont get expired?

Comment: You only want to add a TTL index on `scheduledDate` with the idea that you only should remove records after they have been sent successfully, otherwise have a look at RikkusRikkus solution,

Answer (score -4):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let PassWordReSate = new Schema(
  {
    hex: String,
    email: String,
  },
  {
    collection: "PassWordReSate",
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
PassWordReSate.path("createdAt").index({ expires: 6 });
module.exports = mongoose.model("PassWordReSate", PassWordReSate);
```