# Delete all records older than 3 months from current date Mongodb node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my application I have activity logs of users stored in my DB (mongoDB), Since a lot of logs are collected within 3 months **I want to Delete all the activity log records older than 3 months from current date**. I using Node.js for my backend. **I want to run this function everyday automatically**. Please help me with this.

This is the Log model

```
const logSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    activityType: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
      enum: {
        values: [
          'create',
          'update',
          'delete',
          'login',
          'logout',
          'passwordReset',
        ],
        message: 'Wrong activity type!',
      },
    },
    activitySubject: {
      type: Object,
      require: true,
    },
    activityPerformedUserId: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Log = mongoose.model('log', logSchema);

module.exports = Log;
```

This is how my activity log document looks like.

```
{
  "_id": "62788f467a6d842face8a698",
  "activityType": "delete",
  "activitySubject": {
  "id": "627557836752492b6c7ff515",
  "name": "S Thomson",
  "nic": "78456123442"
  },
  "activityPerformedUserId": "6276ab95eb9e634310ea37f8",
  "createdAt": "2022-05-09T03:49:26.510Z",
  "updatedAt": "2022-05-09T03:49:26.510Z"
}
```

Comment: Create a function that will delete old records, and call the function every day.

Comment: Can you please show an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here it would be like

```
const a =  {
  "_id": "62788f467a6d842face8a698",
  "activityType": "delete",
  "activitySubject": {
    "id": "627557836752492b6c7ff515",
    "name": "S Thomson",
    "nic": "78456123442"
  },
  "activityPerformedUserId": "6276ab95eb9e634310ea37f8",
  "createdAt": "2022-05-09T03:49:26.510Z",
  "updatedAt": "2022-05-09T03:49:26.510Z"
}
```

Try this:

```
a.splice(a.findIndex(e => new Date(e.createdAt + 2592000000 ) > new Date()),1);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best feature of MongoDB which deletes the record to granular level precision is [TTL](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/)

Create a field on which the entire document will be removed after that time has passed. For ex, if you want to delete a record on x day, y hour, z minute, then set the value of the TTL field to `x y z`.

In your case, you can set `TTL` field to `createdAt` + 90 days, so that it will remove it after 90 days from `createdAt` value

Comment: Can you please show an example.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178356/create-a-conditional-ttl-in-mongo) will help you to understand more

Comment: This is what I figured => logSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 7889238 }); is it okay to define 3 months in seconds like this.

Comment: Yes, you can define. If you want to try it out, set smaller value and see it in action

Comment: I tried it and it's working for 60 seconds... But is it okay to set 3 months in seconds. Or is there another way or property like expireAfterMonth ?

Comment: It's the correct way to set it. Don't worry, go ahead.